# How to detect the Simulator and Device code in Xcode?

Tags: iphone

I am using AVCaptureSession class to capture video. This class only active for Device mode. Other functionality working both simulator and device. How to handle this class for Simulator mode. Whether i have to command this class? please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using three methods :

- At compilation, by using preprocessor directive :

  ```
  #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  // simulator code
  #else
  // device code
  #endif
  ```
- At runtime (more complex), by checking device :

  ```
  // Simple version :
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
     // code
  }
  ```

  OR

  ```
  // More precise version:
  - (NSString *) platform{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
  }

  - (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPodTouch1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPodTouch2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPodTouch3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPodTouch4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad2Wifi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad2GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad2CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"iPhoneSimulator";
    return platform;
  }
  ```
- At project build settings by excluding files depending on SDK (even more complex, but useful for librairies) :

  ```
  "EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES[sdk=iphoneos*][arch=*]" = ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way now! As of Xcode 9.3 beta 4 you can use `#if targetEnvironment(simulator)` to check.